# Change the color of the property-value in .json file in VSCode

Tags: visual-studio-code

I'm trying to customize the color of the property-value keywords (reserved values) for .css and .scss files in the .json file in VSCode. I tried:

```
    "editor.tokenColorCustomizations":{
      "textMateRules": [
        {
        "name": "CSS Class and Support - Class",
        "scope": [
        "source.css entity.other.attribute-name.class.css",
        "source.sass entity.other.attribute-name.class.css",
        "source.scss entity.other.attribute-name.class.css",
        "source.less entity.other.attribute-name.class.css",
        "source.stylus entity.other.attribute-name.class.css",
        "source.postcss entity.other.attribute-name.class.css"
      ],
      "settings": {
      "foreground": "#f56464"
      }
     }
    ]
   }
```

But this didn't change the color of the property-value keywords.

I appreciate any help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You are using the `attribute-name.class` scopes which appear to be the selectors like `.myClass`.  It is working for those.

If by "property-value" keywords you mean something like `background-color` or `border` then this works:

```
"editor.tokenColorCustomizations":{
  "textMateRules": [
   {
      "name": "CSS Property Names",
      "scope": [
        "support.type.property-name.css",
        // etc.
    ],
    "settings": {
      "foreground": "#f56464"
    }
   }
 ]
}
```

Comment: No No. I mean by the property value something like `center` for `justify-content` property or something like `right` for the `text-align` property. @Mark

Comment: What you wrote above will change the colors of the properties (`justify-content`, `text-align`) not the values themselves.

Comment: You want both the property keys and values changed?

Comment: Yes. Anyway, I got the solution. Thanks alot for your valuable contribution.